# How can I render only first object from array? React Native Flatlist

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

How can I render only first object from Array?? I know that I need to put [0] but I don't know where exactly? I tried item[0] and item.answers[0]. Is there any other way of doing it? I don't know what else to write so system allow me to post my question. lol

```
const DATA = [
  {
    id: "2222",
    question:
      "In class, how often do you purposely encourage others around you?",
    answers: [
      {
        answerText:
          "Bully: Use physical aggression to get my own way. Pick on others a lot",
      }
    ],
  },
  {
    id: "3333",
    question:
      "In class, how often do you purposely encourage others around you?",
    answers: [
    
      {
        answerText:
          "Manipulating: Try to get others to do what you want by telling",
      },
    ],
  },
];

const Item = ({ item, onPress, style }) => {
  return item.answers
    .map((x) => x.answerText)
    .map((value, i) => (
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={onPress}
        style={[styles.item, style]}
        keyExtractor={i}
      >
        <Text style={styles.title}>{value}</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    ));
};

const renderItem = ({ item }) => {
    // const backgroundColor = item.id === selectedId ? "#6e3b6e" : "#f9c2ff";
    return (
      <Item
        item={item}
        onPress={() => {
          console.log(item);
        }}
        style={{ backgroundColor: Colors.primary }}
      />
    );
  };

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <FlatList
        data={DATA}
        renderItem={renderItem}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
      />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Render item function provide also index argument, you may check, if index!=0 than return null

Answer (score 0):

This might help

```
const Item = ({ item, onPress, style }) => {
  return <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={onPress}
          style={[styles.item, style]}
         >
         <Text style={styles.title}>{item.answers[0].answerText}</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
};
```

Comment: It should work I think so. I have updated, please check

Comment: No it doesn't work and real solution of problem is different, which I found already